# applyImpulse not triggering

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I've defined the gravity as 0 in the `initWithSize` method and then in the touchesBegan i've set it to -5 so when you touch the screen the app will start the problem is in the touchesBegan method i've also implemented an applyImpulse, but it does not trigger. It is only the gravity that is being triggered. This means the mover just falls to the button.

How come the applyImpulse not being triggered?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake( 0.0, -5.0 );
    mover.physicsBody.restitution = 0.0;
    mover.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);
    [mover.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 15)];

}
```

and the mover method:

```
-(void)addMover:(CGSize) size {


    SKTexture* lolTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lol1"]];
    lolTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    SKTexture* lolTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lol2"]];
    lolTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    SKTexture* lolTexture3 = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lol3"]];
    lolTexture3.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    SKTexture* lolTexture4 = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lol4"]];
    lolTexture4.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    SKTexture* lolTexture5 = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lol5"]];
    lolTexture5.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    SKTexture* lolTexture6 = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lol6"]];
    lolTexture6.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    SKAction *flap = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[lolTexture1, lolTexture2, lolTexture3, lolTexture4, lolTexture5, lolTexture6] timePerFrame:0.15]];

    SKSpriteNode *mover = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:lolTexture1];
    [mover setScale:1.0];

    mover.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 4, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    [mover runAction:flap withKey:@"birdGo"];

    [self addChild:mover];

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake( 0.0, 0 );

    mover.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:mover.frame.size.width/2-7];
```

}

Comment: You are creating your 'mover' sprite in the addMover method which limits its scope to only that method but yet you have a "mover" object in the touchesBegan: method. Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare mover outside of addMover so that you can use it in touchesBegan method.

SKSpriteNode *mover;

Then in addMover

mover = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:lolTexture1];